# c# xamarin circular progress bar - Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-progressbar

created a circular progress bar which is working fine with the animation. but while trying to display it using dynamic data progress bar is not updating.

Below code is working

```
  progrssBarObj = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBarSync);

  ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.OfInt(progrssBarObj, "progress", 0, 100); // see this max value coming back here, we animale towards that value
  animation.SetDuration(3000); //in milliseconds
  animation.SetInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
  animation.Start();
```

and AXML code is

```
<ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:id="@+id/progressBarSync"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
            android:background="@drawable/progress_bar_background" />
```

But when I tried something like in the loop the progress bar is not updating with the data. Basically progress bar is not updating in circle.

```
           for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                int cnt = 0;
                cnt = cnt + i;
                progrssBarObj.Progress = cnt;

            }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I kept the for loop inside in new task and it got worked

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
  for (int i = 0; i < dtITM.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    int cnt = 0;
    cnt = cnt + i;
    progrssBarObj.Progress = cnt;
  }
}
```